# DatePicker readonly

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker

Please help me.

I have date picker and I want user just `readonly`, and not change the date has selected.

```html
<td class="contentdata fontSize07">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="EntDate1" id="date1" class="textinputdasar fontSize08 marginLeft1" placeholder="Entertainment Date" value="<?php echo $EntDate1 ?>" required>
    <div class="margine1"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Defeats the purpose of a date*PICKER* imho

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `readonly` in html that will disable the input filed to accept value.

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="2/2/2019" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td class="contentdata fontSize07"><input readonly type="text" autocomplete="off" name="EntDate1" id="date1" class="textinputdasar fontSize08 marginLeft1" placeholder="Entertainment Date" value="<?php echo $EntDate1 ?>" required><div class="margine1"></div></td>
```

Add `readonly` attribute to the input